# Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have tried following script to send mail through phpmailer

```
 <?php
        $sendfrm_name = 'Balakumar B';
        $sendfrm_id = 'user1@gmail.com';

        $sendtoname = 'myself';
        $sendto = 'user2@mydomain.com';

        //$cc = '';

        include("mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
        include("mail/class.PHPMailer.php");
        include("mail/class.smtp.php");

        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        //$mail-> isSMTP();
        $mail-> Host = 'mail.mydomain.com'; //smtp.gmail.com
        $mail->SMTPDebug   = 2;
        $mail-> SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->smtpConnect = array(
        'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
        );
        $mail-> Username = 'balakumar@mydomain.com';
        $mail-> Password = 'balakumar1`2345';
        $mail-> SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail-> Port = 465; //587
        $mail-> setFrom($sendfrm_id, $sendfrm_name);
        $mail-> addAddress($sendto, $sendtoname);
        $mail-> addReplyTo($sendto, $sendtoname);
        //$mail->addCC($cc);
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "Test Mail";
        $mail->Body = "Name: ".$sendfrm_name ."<br /> Email: ".$sendfrm_id;
        if(!$mail->send())
        {
            echo "Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
        else
        {
            echo ("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
                echo "E-mail: ", $sendto, "<br />";
                echo "Name: ", $sendtoname, "<br />";
                echo "Subject: Test Mail<br />";
                echo "Body: Body Of the Mail<br />";

        } 
 ?>
```

But I got Mailer Error:

> Could not instantiate mail function.

How to fix this error? Above I have mentioned my mailserver (mail.mydomain.com) and Port 465.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a whole load of things wrong here, for no particular reason I can see.

When you're using the autoloader, you don't need to load the other classes - that's what the autoloader is for. It looks like you have changed the filename of `class.phpmailer.php` to `class.PHPMailer.php`, which is non-standard and will have trouble on case-sensitive file systems, and may break when you update your libraries.

If you don't call `isSMTP()`, you won't be using SMTP, so none of the SMTP settings will be used (it will use the PHP `mail()` function by default).

If you use `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`, you need `Port = 587`, not 465.

Why are you disabling certificate verification? You should only do that for very specific reasons, not just as a random measure to "make it work". It represents a security risk, so don't do it unless you absolutely have to, and you know the exact reason why - if you don't know, don't do it.

There's no need to call `WordWrap` - it also suggests you've based your code on an old example and may be running an old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Why are you setting the to and reply-to addresses to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is for default `mail()` function of php. You need to use SMTP.

You have disabled SMTP.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//$mail-> isSMTP(); <----------- Here it is disabled.
$mail-> Host = 'mail.mydomain.com'; //smtp.gmail.com
$mail->SMTPDebug   = 2;
$mail-> SMTPAuth = true;
```

Because SMTP is disabled it is using `mail()` function. Which is not configured properly in your machine.

Just uncomment that line it should work.

Full code here:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail-> isSMTP(); # SMTP is enabled now.
$mail-> Host = 'mail.mydomain.com'; //smtp.gmail.com
$mail->SMTPDebug   = 2;
$mail-> SMTPAuth = true;
```

Hope this helps.